# phpinfo() mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, php

I'm attempting to perform some url rewriting, and after looking at the phpinfo file, I can't see any mention of this.. My host is FastHosts.

Should I be looking for something else in the `phpinfo()` or should I assume that `mod_rewrite` is simply `disabled`?

Comment: Why not just try using `mod_rewrite` and see what happens?

Comment: mod_rewrite is an extension to Apache, not PHP.  I don't think it will appear in your phpinfo output.  If you can't look at the actual server configuration, I recommend you create an .htaccess file in some directory and try to configure mod_rewrite in there, to see if it works.

Comment: That's what I've done, and nothing was working so I wanted to be 100% sure it was disabled (and not my wonky code).   I now know it IS disabled, any way of enabling it?

Comment: Did you try Emil H's solution? It should work. Worked for me!

Answer (score 11):

`mod_rewrite` is an apache module, not a PHP module. It isn't visible in `phpinfo()`. Create an .htaccess in some subfolder and make sure it contains:

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Point your browser to the folder. If you get a Server Error, it isn't installed. Otherwise it is.

Comment: I've found out it is installed :)   Would changes I make to .htaccess (url re-write rules) take effect immediately or would it need a restart from the webhost?

Comment: I believe that they take effect without restarting Apache, yes.

Comment: @EmilH yes it should. htaccess changes take in effect instantly

Comment: @EmilH phpinfo(); displays also web server info if executed by web call

Answer (score 8):

When PHP gets used as an Apache module **apache_get_modules()** can be used to check this

```
<?php
print_r(apache_get_modules());
?>
```

which then gives a result like this:

```
Array
(
   [0] => core
   [1] => http_core
   [2] => mod_so
   [3] => sapi_apache2
   [4] => mod_mime
   [5] => mod_rewrite
)
```

**apache_get_modules() does not work if you are using PHP as CGI**

Answer (score 1):

This works on Debian:

```
apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
```

Comment: On a PHP specific question you should mention backticks or whatever way to execute that command line statement from a PHP script don't you think? Otherwise nice.

Answer (score 0):

I had followed all the procedures to enable the mod rewrite. But it just didn't seem to work.

I had even added the floowing piece of code correctly to the `.conf` file but to no avail.

```
<Directory “/var/www/html”>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

But then I noticed, Those inverted commas don't look normal!!! Bam!! Replaced those peskies with correct ones and Wah-Lah!!!