# php script(function) to check if .htaccess is allowed on server

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

as title says I am looking for a PHP function to check if you can use .htaccess file on your server.

What should I test for ?

Option 1:
<del>Maybe if **mod_rewrite** module is installed ?</del>

Option 2:
Check out if "**AllowOverride None**" presented in '**httpd.conf**'.

Thank you for your suggestions, code will help too ;)

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772892/phpinfo-mod-rewrite

Comment: Checking for mod_rewrite is won't help. You can have it not installed, but still have .htaccess files.

Comment: Check your web-hosts documentation.  Every web-host I have visited/researched notifies you somewhere if you have .htaccess rewrite capabilities.  If they don't advertise that as a benefit, then chances are likely (as most ppl these days are wanting that privilege) they don't offer that as a feature

Comment: @JTSmith I am trying to write a PHP function to check this automaticly. This is part of my _requirements script_ to check if all necessary functions are enabled on server to full functionality of appliaction on each server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a .htaccess file with your php script, write a redirect into it for some file, and then call the file and check if it's redirected. Should be one of the most basic ways to check if .htaccess works.

Edit: Not tested

```
<?php
$html1 = "test.html";
$html2 = "test2.html";
$htaccess = ".htaccess";
$string1 = "<html><head><title>Hello</title></head><body>Hello World</body></html>";
$string2 = "<html><head><title>Hello</title></head><body>You have been redirected</body></html>";
$string3 = "redirect 301 /test.html /test2.html";
$handle1 = fopen($html1, "w");
$handle2 = fopen($html2, "w");
$handle3 = fopen($htaccess, "w");

fwrite($handle1, $string1);
fwrite($handle2, $string2);
fwrite($handle3, $string3);

$http = curl_init($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/test.html");
$result = curl_exec($http);
$code = curl_getinfo($http, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if($code == 301) {
    echo ".htaccess works";
} else {
    echo ".htaccess doesn't work";
}
?>
```

Comment: At least when using mod_php you could also use `virtual()` to perform a (fake) http request.

Comment: @ThiefMaster how to fake that http request ? (sample code) please

Comment: @ing. Michal Hudak You really need to start to figure things out a bit, you can't just post some problem and expect everyone to write the whole code for you.

Comment: @Ahatius I am setting up function by my self. Not requesting whole solving problem. I never worked with `virtual()` function before. I know the syntax but not how to use it with `curl()`.

Answer (score 14):

In .htaccess, simply put something like:

```
SetEnv HTACCESS on
```

Then, in your PHP-script, look for it in $_SERVER:

```
if ( !isset($_SERVER['HTACCESS']) ) {
  // No .htaccess support
}
```

Comment: @Mickle So basically you can put there anything and check if it is set on ? like: `SetEnv SomeVariable on` and then check if `$_SERVER['SomeVariable']` is set ? By the way instead of `!isset` use `empty`. `!isset` will not work.

Comment: Why do you think !isset() will not work? It's worked perfectly for me so far. In this case though, empty can be used instead, as you say.